# Relationships SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently doing a project with SQL Server. I am not too familiar with this programming language, and I am required to create relationships. The relationships I have created are

- Pet/Owner (One-To-Many)
- Pet/Appointment (One-to-One)
- Appointment/Vet (One-to-One).

I have looked on Google and YouTube, and I THINK my code is correct.

Can someone double check my work before I start to add data?

```
CREATE TABLE Vet
(
     [VET_NUM] CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
     [LAST_NAME] CHAR(20),
     [FIRST_NAME] CHAR(20),
     [STREET] CHAR(30),
     [CITY] CHAR(20),
     [STATE] CHAR(20),
     [POSTAL_CODE] CHAR(20),
     [SALARY] DECIMAL(8,2),
     [DEGREE] CHAR(20),
     [POSITION] CHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Owner
(
     [OWNER_NUM] CHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
     [OWNER_NAME] CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     [STREET] CHAR(30),
     [CITY] CHAR(20),
     [STATE] CHAR(20),
     [POSTAL_CODE] CHAR(20),
     [PET_NUM] CHAR(5)
);

CREATE TABLE Appointment
(
     [APPOINTMENT_NUM] CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
     [APPOINTMENT_DATE] DATE,
     [VET_NUM] CHAR(3)
     [PET_NUM] CHAR(3) 
);

CREATE TABLE Pet 
(
     [PET_NUM] CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
     [PET_NAME] CHAR(35) NOT NULL,
     [STREET] CHAR(30),
     [CITY] CHAR(15),
     [STATE] CHAR(2),
     [POSTAL_CODE] CHAR(5),
     [BREED] CHAR(20),
     [OWNER_NUM] CHAR(3),
     [APPOINTMENT_NUM] CHAR(5) 
);
```

Comment: you have not created the foreign keys

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Sami Definitely not. One of the requirements for posting on Code Review is the code should work to the best of OP's knowledge. OP doesn't have a clue, so it's not welcome there.

Comment: As @AmanB said. You created only the tables, there is no relationship between then beside the column names. Also, makes no sense a column `PET_NUM` be of type `CHAR(3)`give approprieated types to your columns values.

Comment: Suggestions:  Use Int for primary key, or big int if you expect more that ~2 billion records.  Make Pets -> Appointments one to many.  Consider Varchar and only limit to less than (8000) when there is a good reason. Then create the foreign keys others mentioned and you should be good.

Comment: Also don't forget to add indexes to your FKs. Btw you *can* add data before adding constraints and indexes since they don't change de data (of course is advisabele to add your constraints and "obvious" indexes before).

Comment: Given your admitted lack of understanding, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your design. Please use this

```
    USE[zz_CIS245_16]
GO

CREATE TABLE Vet
(
    [VET_NUM] INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT Pk_Vet_VetNum PRIMARY KEY,
    [LAST_NAME] CHAR(20),
    [FIRST_NAME] CHAR(20),
    [STREET] CHAR(30),
    [CITY] CHAR(20),
    [STATE] CHAR(20),
    [POSTAL_CODE] CHAR(20),
    [SALARY] DECIMAL(8,2),
    [DEGREE] CHAR(20),
    [POSITION] CHAR(20)
);


CREATE TABLE Owner
(
    [OWNER_NUM] INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT Pk_Owner_OwnerNum PRIMARY KEY,
    [OWNER_NAME] CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    [STREET] CHAR(30),
    [CITY] CHAR(20),
    [STATE] CHAR(20),
    [POSTAL_CODE] CHAR(20)
    --[PET_NUM] CHAR(5) -- Removed as duplicate (Owner Num already exists in Pet)
);


CREATE TABLE Pet
(
    [PET_NUM] INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT Pk_Pet_PetNum PRIMARY KEY,
    [PET_NAME] CHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    [STREET] CHAR(30),
    [CITY] CHAR(15),
    [STATE] CHAR(2),
    [POSTAL_CODE] CHAR(5),
    [BREED] CHAR(20),
    [OWNER_NUM] INT CONSTRAINT Fk_Pet_OwnerNum FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Owner(OWNER_NUM),-- Added Foreign key reference 
    [APPOINTMENT_NUM] CHAR(5) 
)

CREATE TABLE Appointment
(
    [APPOINTMENT_NUM] INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT Pk_Appointment_AppointmentNum PRIMARY KEY,
    [APPOINTMENT_DATE] DATE,
    [VET_NUM] INT UNIQUE NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Fk_Appointment_VetNum FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES VET(VET_NUM),-- Added Foreign key reference  );
    [PET_NUM] INT UNIQUE NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Fk_Appointment_PetNum FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Pet(PET_NUM)-- Added Foreign key reference  );
)
```

Comment: If you're going to provide a solution with words like "Please use this", then you should be much more complete in your answer.  What have you changed, and why?  Why don't you have any indexes?  Why did you leave the `PRIMARY KEY` fields as `CHAR(x)` and not change to `INT IDENTITY`?  Why are your `FOREIGN KEY`s not the same types as the `PRIMARY KEY`s?  *(`Owner.Owner_Num` is `CHAR(20)` and yet `Pet.Owner_Num` is `CHAR(3)`)*.  Why do your foreign keys have `UNIQUE` constraints? *(Can one vet only have one appointment?)* There is so much missing here that I'm marking it down until updated.

Comment: @MatBailie I've updated the Primark key, I already have added the description on my changes in the comments

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Foreign Keys to support the relationships, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE Owner     
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Owner_Pet FOREIGN KEY (PET_NUM)     
    REFERENCES Pet (PET_NUM)     
    ON DELETE CASCADE    
    ON UPDATE CASCADE    
;    
GO
```

This implements a one-to-many relationship.

I don't think you really want one-to-one relationships.  Will a PET only ever have one APPOINTMENT?  Will a VET only ever have one APPOINTMENT?